# Problema ao utilizar Url Amigável

Tags: htaccess, apache, url-amigável

Aonde estou errando nesse .htaccess ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

o site que desenvolvi funciona normalmente no localhost, mas agora que subi para o servidor (Cpanel Hostgator), as páginas não abrem corretamente, vejam o exemplo.

[image: Exemplo 1]

se eu clicar no link, a URL redireciona corretamente para `novosite.glowseguros.com.br/home/produtos/seguro-auto#produto`
mas a pagina não muda, continua na Home.

agora se eu colocar .php igual eu fiz na imagem abaixo a pagina é exibida corretamente. 
`novosite.glowseguros.com.br/home/produtos.php/seguro-auto#produto`

[image: Exemplo 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O apache do servidor estava com a opção Multiviews desabilitada.

Foi só forçar a opção através do .htaccess que o problema foi resolvido. adicionei a seguinte linha no arquivo

```
Options +MultiViews
```